# Angular 2: How to pass innerHTML of an <a> tag to an event?

Tags: angular

`<a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#" (click)="clicked(this)">Home</a>`
I would like the text(in this case "Home") to clicked. And I want to do it with Angular.

Comment: `<a #atag class="breadcrumb-item" href="#" (click)="clicked(atag)">Home</a>`

Comment: Oke, that's good! And than I can do x.innerHTML?

Comment: Do you expect html code to be inside your a-tags ? Or just simple text like in the example?

Comment: Just simple text  @matt

Comment: Why not make "home" a property in your component and then pass it like this ``(click)="clicked(myHomeVar)">{{myHomeVar}}</a>``

Comment: Yes that's possible too, but I'd like to see what's inside of the tag. Because the user will be able to change that <a> text. Its not possible what I would like?

Comment: You mean the directives in the  a-tag like ``class="breadcrumb-item"`` ? If so, then anshuVersatile's proposal is the way to go. You need to define a ViewChild in your component and access its nativeElement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134694/discussion-between-matt-and-arnold).